# Cómo imprimir alfabeto de forma intercalada en c#

Tags: c#, consola, imprimir

Necesito imprimir en pantalla, mediante el uso de dos Tareas, el alfabeto de forma intercalada. Es decir, que cada tarea imprima una letra intercalandose.

Algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya implementé el código para que trabajen en paralelo las tareas. Sin embargo, no he podido lograr a que se impriman de forma intercalada.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Alphabet abc = new Alphabet();

            Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(abc.alphabetA);
            Task taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(abc.alphabetB);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

 class Alphabet
    {

        public Alphabet() { }


        public void alphabetA()
        {
            for(int i='A';i<'Z';i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine((char)i+"|");
                
            }
        }

        public void alphabetB()
        {
            for (int i = 'A'; i < 'Z'; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine((char)i);
               

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Podrías manejar la posición de las letras en el abecedario como pares e impares.. es una buena opción 

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Yo quiero creer que este es un ejercicio sobre semaforos no? porque asi como esta, no va a hacer jamas eso que pedis... aca necesitas semaforos y alertar al otro thread cuando puede trabajar...

Comment: Tu problema seria que queres intecarlar las letras o queres intercalar las letras usando Task para hacer algun tipo de prueba? Porque si es la segunda opcion no podes manipular de esa forma el tiempo que el sistema le da a cada una, aunque parezca obvio que no deberia suceder eso.\